# Cannot find trait implementations for associated types

Tags: rust

I have code that used to work on nightly-2016-11-15. When I upgraded to 1.15.1 stable, I started getting a bunch of errors about type implementations not being found. Here's an example:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `errors::Error: core::convert::From<r2d2_postgres::<unnamed>::error::Error>` is not satisfied
  --> src/pg/datastore.rs:79:23
   |
79 |         let results = conn.query("DELETE FROM accounts WHERE id=$1 RETURNING 1", &[&account_id])?;
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `core::convert::From<r2d2_postgres::<unnamed>::error::Error>` is not implemented for `errors::Error`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
   = help:   <errors::Error as core::convert::From<r2d2_postgres::Error>>
   = help:   <errors::Error as core::convert::From<postgres::error::Error>>
   = help:   <errors::Error as core::convert::From<r2d2::GetTimeout>>
   = help:   <errors::Error as core::convert::From<rocksdb::Error>>
   = help: and 3 others
   = note: required by `core::convert::From::from`
```

... even though there is a relevant `From` implementation. Here's a shortened version:

```
use std::error::Error as StdError;
use r2d2::GetTimeout;
use postgres::error::Error as PostgresError;
use r2d2_postgres::Error as R2D2PostgresError;
use super::fmt;

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    Unexpected(String),
    ...
}

impl StdError for Error {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        ...
    }

    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&StdError> {
        None
    }
}

impl From<R2D2PostgresError> for Error {
    fn from(err: R2D2PostgresError) -> Error {
        Error::Unexpected(format!("{}", err))
    }
}

impl From<PostgresError> for Error {
    fn from(err: PostgresError) -> Error {
        Error::Unexpected(pg_error_to_description(err))
    }
}

impl From<GetTimeout> for Error {
    fn from(err: GetTimeout) -> Error {
        Error::Unexpected(format!("Could not fetch connection: {}", err))
    }
}
```

I think this has something to do with the use of associated types, as it doesn't appear to happen in other contexts. Additionally, the namespace `r2d2_postgres::<unnamed>::error::Error` doesn't make sense - what is `<unnamed>`? Here is [the relevant type association](https://github.com/sfackler/r2d2-postgres/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L112).

Comment: Sorry, I was worried that the question was already getting too wordy, and that the answer might be obvious to others. I'll flesh it out further.

Comment: After taking the presented code and making it compile (adding extern crates, implementing `Display`, correcting imports, removing `...`, etc. — all signs that you didn't test this code locally) the code compiles without the error you say. It's fairly unlikely that you will get any useful help until you provide a [MCVE]. Specifically, an answer is most likely when someone can copy directly from your question, paste it locally, and get the same error message.

Comment: @Shepmaster as stated in the conversation we had before you deleted your comments, I've been having trouble creating a minimal example. This question, in general, has been difficult to disentangle because it's part of a large codebase that is not (yet) open source. I'll leave a comment though on what fixed it for me, for posterity.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my comments because I saw you had updated the question and removed the text that indicated that the example doesn't reproduce the problem, which I took to mean that the example now reproduced the problem. At that point, I thought my comments were irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be due to version conflicts. I had switched to `postgres`'s master branch to fix a separate version conflict, but `r2d2_postgres` was referencing a different version of `postgres`.

Luckily, as explained in [this issue](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/issues/235), `Cargo.toml` has a `[replace]` section that allows you to handle it like this:

```
[replace]
"postgres:0.13.6" = { git = "https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres" }
```